# Enqueue, Register & Load CSS and JavaScript with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm a beginner in WordPress, in WordPress is there a way to load JS/CSS file to a specific page, when page is called, and not to load it on an other one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading `scripts` and `stylesheet` from the `function.php` file is **the best practice** with Wordpress.

> Adding scripts and styles to WordPress is a fairly simple process.
> Essentially, you will create a function that will enqueue all of your
> scripts and styles.

*Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/*

With Wordpress you can register a `script` and `stylesheet` before actually enqueuing it. We use some really handy functions called `wp_register_script` / `wp_register_style` for `scripts` and `wp_enqueue_script` / `wp_enqueue_style` for `stylesheet`. **You should pay attention and read about the functions arguments**

Together with some conditional tags and functions we end up building really complex behaviours to conditionally register and enqueue `scripts` and `stylesheet` on our theme and pages. **You should pay attention and read about the functions arguments.**

> The Conditional Tags can be used in your Template files to change what
> content is displayed and how that content is displayed on a particular
> page depending on what conditions that page matches.

*Source @ https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags*

For example `is_home()`, `is_search()`, `is_single()` or `is_page()`... can be used to conditionally register and enqueue `scripts` and `stylesheet` on our different pages.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
function theme_scripts() {
  if( ! is_admin() ) {

    /**
    * Register then enqueue jquery_js
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
    */
    wp_register_script( 'jquery_js', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array(), '3.5.1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js' );
  };
}; ?>
```

In this example we only want to enqueue our `jquery-3.5.1.min.js` if we are on a different page than an admin's one, using `if ( ! is_admin() )...`.

---

### Register, Enqueue and CDNs

`script` and `stylesheet` can be hosted locally or on a different server (eg: CDNs). When using CDNs, we want to make sure that the source is available. We can use `@fopen();` to make sure the CDN is reachable, and if not, serve a fallback:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
function theme_scripts() {
  if( ! is_admin() ) {

    /**
    * Register then enqueue jquery_js
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
    *
    * Check if CDN's url is valid, if not return fallback
    * @link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
    */
    $test_jquery_js = @fopen( 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', 'r' );
    if( $test_jquery_js !== false ) {
      wp_register_script( 'jquery_js', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array(), '3.5.1', true );
    } else {
      wp_register_script( 'jquery_js', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array(), '3.5.1', true );
    };
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js' );
  };
}; ?>
```

---

### Adding Attributes (eg: Crossorigin, Integrity)

Sometimes it is required to add attributes to `script` and `stylesheet` tags, to properly enqueue them. Using the `script_loader_tag` or `style_loader_tag` hook, we can do just that:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
function theme_scripts() {
  if( ! is_admin() ) {

    /**
    * Register then enqueue jquery_js
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
    *
    * Check if CDN's url is valid, if not return fallback
    * @link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
    *
    * Add rel='preload' <link> and required attributes to jquery_js
    * Filters the HTML link tag of an enqueued style & add required attributes
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/
    */
    $test_jquery_js = @fopen( 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', 'r' );
    if( $test_jquery_js !== false ) {
      wp_register_script( 'jquery_js', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array(), '3.5.1', true );
    } else {
      wp_register_script( 'jquery_js', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array(), '3.5.1', true );
    };
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js' );

    add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'data_jquery_js', 10, 3 );
    function data_jquery_js( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
      if( $handle === 'jquery_js' ) {
        $integrity = 'sha256...';
        $tag = str_replace(
          array(
            "<script",
            "></script>",
          ),
          array(
            "<link rel='preload prefetch' href='" . esc_url( $src ) . "' as='script' integrity='" . $integrity . "' crossorigin='anonymous' />" . PHP_EOL . "<script",
            "integrity='" . $integrity . "' crossorigin='anonymous' async></script>",
          ),
          $tag
        );
      };
      return $tag;
    };
  };
}; ?>
```

Here, we are adding a `preload` link tag, the `crossorigin`, `integrity` and the `async` attribute.

---

### Always register?

If you don't need to register your `script` or `stylesheet` prior to enqueuing it, you can actually ignore it. eg:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array(), '3.5.1', true  );
```

Here we don't register our script and jump straight to the enqueue.

---

### jQuery already part of Wordpress core?

With Wordpress, jQuery is normally pre-registered, and comes with the core. If you want to enqueue your own version you MUST deregister the core jQuery version.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
function theme_scripts() {
  if( ! is_admin() ) {

    /**
    * Deregister Wordpress jquery core version
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_script/
    */
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    //...here goes the rest of your function...
  };
}; ?>
```

---

### Enqueue and register a `script` or `stylesheet` on the admin side

Using the admin_enqueue_scripts action hook, you can do just that.

```
<?php
do_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_scripts' );
function admin_scripts() {
  //...here goes the rest of your function...
}; ?>
```

---

### Learn more

- `wp_register_script` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/.
- `wp_register_style` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/.
- `wp_enqueue_script` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/.
- `wp_enqueue_style` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/.
- `fopen()` @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php.
- `script_loader_tag` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/

Answer (score 1):

You could add an if statement to your `<head>` in header.php.

```
<?php if (is_page($id)) { ?>
#css or js here
<?php } ?>
```

Replace `$id` with the ID or slug of the page you want to load the `<script>` or `<style>` on.